# Target browser with java script to change a link

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, targeting

I am trying to target specific browsers and depending on the browser I would like to display different links. My issues is that I have some pdf portfolios but they will only open in IE and the rest of the browsers give a message to download adobe reader. 
My test code:

```
 var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
//For Firefox
if (browser == 'Firefox') {
    document.write('<a href="test.pdf" download="test.pdf">Download</a>');
}
//For Safari
if (browser == 'Safari') {
    document.write('<'+'a href="test.pdf" download="test.pdf">Download</a>');
} 
//For Chrome
if (is_chrome) {
    document.write('<'+'a href="test.pdf" download="test.pdf">Download</a>');
}
//For IE
if(document.documentMode) {
    document.write('<a href="test.pdf">View PDF</a>');
}
```

This is what I have pulled together from searching but is not working. I want to view the pdf if in IE or download it if it is in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Feature detection is recommended over browser detection but in your case I don't think that will help. Here is a good script to detect the browser: [WhichBrowser](https://github.com/WhichBrowser/WhichBrowser)